# Xcode error: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, build, cocoapods, apple-silicon

Never had a lot of problems until the time to buy Macbook Air M1. Just yesterday my app was build without any error in Xcode 12.4. I did not make any special changes and today build failed:

> /Users/userName/Projects/MyApp/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/userName/Projects/MyApp/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a' for architecture arm64clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please can you help me, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing Arm64 simulator slice in the OpenSSL-Universal CocoaPods distribution.

Make sure that you're using the latest version with `pod update` and contact the OpenSSL-Universal if there's still an issue.

Comment: This problem is not related to a missing slice. I experience the same error with another framework witch is a fat binary with all architectures included.

Comment: Old style frameworks don't work for the M1. xcframeworks are needed that provide both a simulator and a device slice for arm64.

Comment: seems like the problem boils down to how the linker distinguishes simulator and native binaries using a flag in a macho binary. Its totally possible to have an 'old-style' fat-framework containing valid architectures and headers to work within all environments, including arm64 simulators. For that to work, the vendor must update the binary though, as the only other solution is to tinker the binary guts, as explained in this excellent article: https://bogo.wtf/arm64-to-sim.html

Comment: i stand corrected, the problem is indeed about a missing slice